# What is difference between targeted protein degrader and protein-targeted degrader?

Tags: american-english, british-english, translation

My question is: Does the position of the word "Targeted" change the meaning of these phrases: **targeted** protein degrader and protein-**targeted** degrader?

Also, please explain what is the meaning of the word "hits" in this sentence: targeted protein degrader **hits** the clinic.

Thank you.

Comment: The second sentence using "hits" is ambiguous. It could mean "targeted protein degrader is now available at the clinic", or it could mean "targeted protein degrader damages the clinic's business." What **is** a "targeted protein degrader" anyway?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. 

About your question: protein degrader is a small molecular that can target disease-causing proteins, such as cancer-causing proteins, to send it to trash. It's a new therapeutic. Instead of inhibiting a protein’s activity by blocking its active site, protein degraded breaks the proteins down entirely.

I read it in here: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41573-019-00043-6

Comment: Whether or not 'protein-targeted degrader' is the more logical according to 'rules' of morphology, one has to look at how idiomatic usages are. **Idiomaticity** (and not logic / patterning) **rules**: _English is usage-driven_. 'Chinese checkers' isn't a form of checkers, nor did it originate in China. Panama hats come from Ecuador. Catgut has never been made from the guts of cats, but from those of sheep. Peanuts aren't nuts. And "I only want to see Thursday's figures" is what most people would say when 'grammar demands' "I want to see only Thursday's figures". So, _which form is used_? Both?

Answer (score 1):

1)  I think it does change the meaning of the sentence considerably. In your first case 
    i.e. `targeted protein degrader` means that the protein degrader is **targeting** some 
    random thing, but it doesn't specify what.

In your second sentence i.e. `protein-targeted degrader`, it specifies that the 
   degrader is targeted towards proteins specifically and not anything else. Also, here 
   the `degrader` is assumed to be separate from a `protein degrader` and if they are the 
   same things, then **both sentences convey the same thing**. So, in short, it 
   depends on where you want to use these words and what are their applications.

2) `Hits the clinic` in this context doesn't literally mean 'hitting the clinic' :P, which 
   is pretty obvious from the way it has been used. Here, it means that when the protein 
   degrader **arrives** at clinic or when it has **reached** the clinic for using it in 
   various purposes or simply when it is **available** for use at the clinic, as pointed out by @Weather Vane.

Cheers!

Edit: After the comment from the OP, I think the whole first point becomes moot. If they are the same things, then there should be no difference to the overall structure of the sentence and thus, both of them seem appropriate to me. But if I were I you, I'd still use the `protein-targeted degrader` as it simply sounds better than the other usage. Also, it shows the specificity in great detail, which may be required.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help. 

1/ Yeah, i believe  degrader and protein degraded are the same things.

Comment: I wouldn't have been too happy with 'building-, antenna-, span- or Earth-jumping', but the [hemi-?]acronym works and is the accepted term. We have to be aware of what people actually use, not just the guidelines, 'rules' of English. If someone calls a quad bike a quad bike, and it catches on, that's the proper way to accept additions to the lexicon. The question is, what did the discoverers / researchers / inventors call the thing, and is that what most people now call it? _What have you found_?

Comment: As I see it: **targeted protein degrader** – something that degrades protein(s) and is capable of being directed (or is designed) so as not to degrade other relevant material. ++ **protein-targeted degrader** – a degrader that is aimed specifically at protein(s) and may or may not affect other material.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @Greybeard on his comment here, but I'll still leave it to the OP on the specifics of the instrument here, as they may be knowing better as to what is the correct term in reality.

Comment: Your answer was more accurate *before* you added the edit. Now it reads, in its entirety, as if you aren't sure of yourself—or as if the first paragraph is wrong. However, I believe that your first paragraph is mostly right. It's **not** the case that hyphenation makes no difference to parsing a phrase.  (And it's not simply that its "sounds better.") Wherever there's any chance of ambiguity, hyphenation is essential. The particular phrase in the question isn't nearly as unambiguous as "hot dog," so hyphenation is critical—unless its being read by a group of people who could have no doubt.

Comment: I'm sorry @JasonBassford, but if the instrument's name specifically doesn't have a hyphen in it then my **edit** would be correct right? I'm not sure if the hyphen is present in the actual term though. You are right that hyphenation does make a pretty big difference (on second thoughts, in this sentence, the hyphen does make a big difference) but in this sentence, I'm not sure if the OP intended to use it there or not. Correct me if I'm wrong, but with regards to the ''sounds better'' thing, English is pretty much built on intuition imo and that's why I think "correct-sounding" matters a lot.

Comment: @Firefox1921 Consider this: *It was a hot dog grooming contest*. That sentence is not immediately obvious. What's it talking about?  A contest that grooms hot dogs, or a dog-grooming contest that's hot? (Forget about the first interpretation being unlikely; I'm just talking about what you can do to make it easier to parse quickly.) To make the meaning clear, a hyphen needs to be added one way or the other. (1) *It was a hot-dog grooming contest.* (2) *It was a hot dog-grooming contest.* Even though *hot dog* is a clearly understood open compound noun, the hyphen would still be needed in (1).

Comment: I don't think so @JasonBassford. If you add a comma in the second sentence (case in point, It was hot, dog grooming contest), it makes more sense, doesn't it? In your second sentence, you're right, hyphenation really is required.

Comment: @Firefox1921 Adding the comma changes the meaning. By doing that, you are turning the phrase into [**coordinate adjectives**](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives). With coordinate adjectives, the comma can be rephrased as a conjunction. *It was a cold, dark night* is the same as *it was a cold **and** dark night.* If you use the comma in the hot dog sentence, it becomes *it was a hot **and** dog grooming contest*. That's not only a different meaning than *it was a hot dog-grooming contest*, but it's actually somewhat nonsensical.

Comment: @JasonBassford Wasn't that what you intended in your earlier comment `... or a dog-grooming contest that's hot?`. I'm sorry, I hadn't noticed them before (and the edit window has also passed) but there are 2 minor edits in my earlier comment: 1) It should have been `...point, It was` **a** `hot...` instead of `...It was hot...`. 2) It should be `...In your` **first** `sentence...` instead of `...In your second sentence...`.

Comment: @Firefox1921 I see the confusion. *It was a dark stormy night* → it was a stormy night that was also dark. But *It was a dark, stormy night* →It was a dark night that was also a stormy night. Without the comma, *dark* modifies *stormy night*. With the comma, *dark* and *stormy* ***separately*** modify night.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh!!. I never knew that they were different! If you could spare some time, could you please elaborate on what you meant by '**separately**' modify the night? How are both of the sentences different and in what way?

Comment: @Firefox1921 I'm afraid such an explanation would be far too involved and inappropriate for comments. Take a look at at the article I linked to in a comment above about the difference between *coordinate adjectives* and *cumulative adjectives*. If after consideration things are still confusing, you might want to ask a question (and mention what you've already learned) to get some clarity.

Comment: Thank You @JasonBassford. I took some time out and searched about the things you had described about and got to know a lot about it. I don't think it will be appropriate if I just post a question without searching about the relevant information first. I sincerely Thank You!! I really appreciate your help.